# Javascript regexp search with capture

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I capture the two integers from the following string into two different variables  using a regexp javascript search?

```
"10 of 25"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex statement is going to be very specific to your strings, so this answer might be specific to whatever your actual use-case is.  However just put the decimals in capturing groups. The .+? In front of those mean "match anything lazily until you find two decimals". 
--So if there is a change you'll have two decimals that shouldn't be captured you'd want to add some extra checks such as a positive lookahead/lookbehind for quotes, etc.

`.+?(\d\d).+?(\d\d).+?`

Simply refer to each capture group as $1, $2, etc.

Use ?: in a group to make it non-capturing, fwiw.

http://regex101.com/r/vN6jO2

Comment: Thanks, great answer so far.  Could you take this a step further and elaborate on how I would use that pattern with a javascript function in order to actually retrieve the captured variables?

Comment: Thanks. Actually on the sandbox I linked to there is </> symbol on the  left side of the screen that will give you code samples.

Comment: Great answer.  I would give you +2 for introducing me to regex101 in the process :P

Comment: Nevermind about the infinite loop.  But how could I allow each decimal to also have an optional decimal place?

Comment: There are a couple ways You could simply follow \d with brackets that indicate the minimum and maximum allowed matches. For example if you wanted to allow just one additional match: `\d{2,3}`.  Or you could append a '?' as a suffix to make a group or escape character optional: `\d?`.  So for you, using an example of each, it would be: `.+?(\d{2,3}).+?(\d\d\d?).+?` [Sandbox Here](http://regex101.com/r/aZ5rS2)